# CSS - How do I place a rectangle in the middle of 2 squares

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make something like this 2 rows of 4 squares , and a rectangle on every middle of 2 squares.

[image]

My current code:

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.square {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.square:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to do a rectangle class :

```
 <div class="square">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
 </div>

.rectangle {
  width: 80%;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
 }
```

But I can't find the way to position the rectangle in the middle of 2 squares. Any help here?

Comment: Have you tried messing around with z-index and position: absolute?

Comment: @ThomasBui i've spent hours and yet to make it

Comment: There are many ways to solve this, would help to know what it's for incase there are restraints

Comment: @Dominic there are no restraints , its just for my personal practice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of putting four rectangles along each border, create two per box with ::before and ::after, and push them to the border of their respective box:

```css
html,body{margin:0}
*{box-sizing:border-box;}

.grid{
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    height: 48vw;
    width: 48vw;
}

.grid:nth-child(2){
    float:left;
}

.item{
    border: solid 2px orange;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.item::before,
.item::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
}

.item::before{
    width: 65%;
    height: 8%;
}

.item::after{
    width: 8%;
    height: 65%;
}

.item:nth-child(1)::before,
.item:nth-child(2)::before{
    bottom: -3px;
}

.item:nth-child(1)::after,
.item:nth-child(3)::after{
    right: -3px;
}

.item:nth-child(2)::after,
.item:nth-child(4)::after{
    left: -3px;
}

.item:nth-child(3)::before,
.item:nth-child(4)::before{
    top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div  class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div  class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Quick question, if i want it to be responsive , i change to `.grid {width: 50%;}` , how do I make the `height` same as the `width` to make it always be a square?

Comment: @hatched make height and width both 50vw (viewport width). You'll have to set them to box-sizing: border-box and remove the body margin as well. See my edit

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier idea with one element:

```css
.square {
  width:50%;
  border:5px solid red;
  background:
    linear-gradient(black,black) left   30px center/ calc(50% - 60px) 40px,
    linear-gradient(black,black) right  30px center/ calc(50% - 60px) 40px,
    linear-gradient(black,black) top    30px center/ 40px calc(50% - 60px),
    linear-gradient(black,black) bottom 30px center/ 40px calc(50% - 60px),

    linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% 5px,
    linear-gradient(red,red) center/5px 100%;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.square:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">

</div>
```

and with CSS variables to easily control everything:

```css
.square {
  --h:30px;  /* Height of square*/
  --b:5px;  /* Thickness of lines*/
  --o:30px; /* Offset of the rectangle from the edge*/
  --c:30px; /* Offset of the rectangle from the center*/

  width:30%;
  display:inline-block;
  border:var(--b) solid red;
  background:
    linear-gradient(black,black) left   var(--o) center/ calc(50% - var(--o) - var(--c)) var(--h),
    linear-gradient(black,black) right  var(--o) center/ calc(50% - var(--o) - var(--c)) var(--h),
    linear-gradient(black,black) top    var(--o) center/ var(--h) calc(50% - var(--o) - var(--c)),
    linear-gradient(black,black) bottom var(--o) center/ var(--h) calc(50% - var(--o) - var(--c)),

    linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% var(--b),
    linear-gradient(red,red) center/var(--b) 100%;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.square:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">

</div>

<div class="square" style="--h:40px;--b:2px;--o:5px;--c:40px">

</div>

<div class="square" style="--h:10%;--b:6px;--o:5%;--c:5%">

</div>
```